# Performing in-place calculations with Commons Math's RealMatrix?

Tags: apache-commons-math

I am using the [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library to perform some calculations and I need to accumulate a number of matrices. The [RealMatrix](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html) interface seems designed to return results, rather than to store results in-place.

Should I just make due with creating lots of short-lived matrices returned from [add()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html#add%28org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix%29) while I accumulate the values? Is there a better alternative?

Were in-place functions intentionally left out for some reason?